# Is there any significance to the negative sign on this speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, speed, relative-motion

A girl is riding a bicycle along a straight road at constant speed, and passes a friend standing at a bus stop (event #$1$). At a time of $60$ s later the friend catches a bus (event #$2$)
If the distance separating the events is 126 m in the frame of the girl on the bicycle, what is the bicycle's speed?

$$u = u' + v$$

can be written as:

$$Δx/t = Δx'/t + v$$

$$v = Δx/t - Δx'/t$$

$$v = 0m/60s - 126m /60s$$

$$v = -126 m/ 60s$$

$$v = -2.1 m/s$$

Just wondering if the negative holds any significance? I know we're talking about speed which is scalar but how come the calculation gives a negative? Sorry I am just beginning to learn about relativity.

Comment: You are going to end up being confused. $\Delta x$ represents the change in $x$, or $x_{final} - x_{initial}$. You should not use $\Delta x$ if you are going to use $x$ and $x'$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful to use the same sign conventions for $x$ and for $v$.  If you're careful enough you can talk about $v$ as a vector with only one component, and take the sign seriously.

Let's choose the positive-$x$ direction to be "towards the right".

- If the bicycle's speed is to the right, $v > 0$, then when the friend catches the bus she's to the left of the cyclist, and $\Delta x'$ should be negative
- You chose the change in position $\Delta x'$ to be positive --- the friend on the bus is at more positive $x$ than the cyclist.  This can only happen if the cyclist is moving to the left, with $v < 0$, as you've found.

For this problem there wasn't a big difference between the two options, since one of the position differences was zero.  However you can easily imagine a problem with the origin in a different place, where having the correct relative signs for $\Delta x$ and $\Delta x'$ is the difference between a right answer and a wrong one.